# exec() not terminating when used with dup2

Tags: c, exec

I am using `dup2()`, `pipe()`, and `fork()` to process commands with input of another.  The output from the `ls` is correctly passed into `cat`, and the terminal displays output, but it does not stop receiving input. In other words cat does not terminate, so I can continue typing.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
int main() {
   int pipefd[2], child_pid, grand_child;

   pipe(pipefd);

   child_pid = fork();

   if (child_pid) {
      waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0);
      /* Parent */

      grand_child = fork();

      if (!grand_child) {
         dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
         close(pipefd[0]);
         close(pipefd[1]);
         execlp("cat", "cat", NULL);
      } else {
         waitpid(grand_child, NULL, 0);
      }

   } else {
      /* Child */

      dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

      close(pipefd[1]);
      close(pipefd[0]);


      execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you are closing `pipefd` before executing `ls`? And same for `cat`.

Comment: Note that waiting for the first child in a pipeline to finish before starting the next is the wrong way to do things.  It forces linear/sequential execution instead of permitting parallel/concurrent execution.  It can also run into blocking if the first process in the pipeline generates so much data that it is blocked waiting for the next process to read some, but the next process is not started because the first hasn't finished yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent still has the write side of the pipe open.  `cat` is waiting for the parent to close it, and the parent is waiting for `cat` to terminate.  You should close both sides of the pipe in the parent before you wait for the grand child.